# Ansible: match whole word in conditional

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

In a conditional like

`changed_when: "'{{ my_var }}' not in users_list`

how do we enforce ansible to match the entire word in the search process?

i.e. assuming:

`my_var: admin`

I want the task to change only when `"admin"` is in `users_list` and not say `"my_admin"`

Ι have tried 
`changed_when: "'\b{{ my_var }}\b' not in users_list`.

Does not seem to work.

Comment: The underscore is a word char. You may try `(?:\b|_)` instead of just `\b`.

Comment: `changed_when: "'(?:\b|_){{ my_var }}(?:\b|_)'  not in users_list` does not seem to work either. Perhaps I am doing sth wrong in the syntax?

Comment: Probably, I can't check now, at the pplayground with kids.

Comment: No worries, thanks either way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `when` statements in Ansible are raw Jinja2 statements. Don't use `{{..}}` inside them.

Second, if `users_list` is a **list**, then `my_var not in users_list` will work fine – it will be true only if there is no `admin` item in the list.

And if `user_list` is a **string** (like: `user1,user2,user3`) you can use `search` test, for example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    users_list: test1,1admin,test2,admin
    my_var: admin
  tasks:
    - command: echo ok
      changed_when: users_list is not search('(^|,)'+my_var+'(,|$)')
```

Comment: Thanks. What I forgot to mention in my q was how to avoid positive check of substring, i.e. if `my_var: admin` and `superadmin` is in `users_list` then the check `my_var in users_list` will return `true` while I would like to have `false`. How to force whole word checking in that case? Removing the curly braces helped a lot either way, thanks for that.

Comment: `search` regexp in my example can handle `superadmin` and trigger only with `admin`, please take a look.